# Exported TOC in LyX centers Part headings

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

I have two matching documents with notes for two different classes. The document class, preamble, etc. are all the same. In one file, when I export it, the TOC centers the Part headings, in the other, the Part headings are Left justified. I want them to be Left justified, but do not understand what coding I may have unintentionally inserted into LyX that would cause the Part headings to center-justify in the TOC. Can somebody help me with this? How do I keep my file from center-justifying the Part headings in the TOC?

I'm using LyX 2.0.6. on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3. I can post screen shots should this be helpful.

UPDATE 1:
%% LyX 2.0.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.

```
\documentclass[10pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Gentium Basic}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{graphicx}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{bibleref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\renewcommand{\bvidxpgformat}{textit}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemiii{\(\triangleright\)}
  \def\labelitemiv{\(\rightarrow\)}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

\title{___}


\author{___}


\date{February 11-14; May 5-9, 2014\pagebreak{}\tableofcontents{}\pagebreak{}}

\maketitle

\part{Introductory Matters}


\section{Introduction}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think you should show us at least some bits of the code and the LyX configuration file.

Comment: Happy to do so! I'm new to this, so let me know if this is what you're asking for. I've added the code for from a Tex file I exported up to the point of the first Part heading in my question above.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously hope this is faulty introduced by the user and not code generated by LyX.

You cannot just call `\tableofcontents` inside the date field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\title{LyX is strange}
\author{Wombat}
%\date{February 11-14; May 5-9, 2014\pagebreak{}\tableofcontents{}\pagebreak{}}% This is rubbish, sorry
\date{In 2014}

\maketitle
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\part{Introductory Matters}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jacob If the table of contents was inserted in the date, then that would generate that code. To fix this in LyX, change "date" to "standard".